EF Core passing 0 as null for ID Column
I have a table with ID as primary key, which can have value 0 (obviously non-repeating). The Id column is not an identity column. While adding a record manually, SQL server allows me to store 0 in ID column. When I am passing the same 0 value from my EF entity model. It is giving me error that inserting null value is not permitted for ID.

As described in the linked duplicate question, EF is likely automatically selecting ID as an identity column and you need to explicitly configure the ID property as not an identity with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)].
